# "Like" in SQL Server to search in (,) separated parameters in String

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am working on a project and I neck is hanging on a query (problem).

I have declared a string of keys with (,) separated in SQL Server. I want to search the data on the base keys in string from some table by using the `LIKE` keyword.

How can I do it?

For example

```
@SearchKey='Game,Movie,Raw'
```

These are some keys that I want to search in table using LIKE keyword

Comment: can you give an example of such a string and the `LIKE` statements you'd want generated?

Comment: @SearchKey='Game,Movie,Raw'    These are some keys that I want to search in table using LIKE keyword

Comment: This should be split out into another table. Read up on first normal form.

Comment: @MartinSmith No, he wants to search for any of those values, not assign multiple values to a single row.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - Ah OK. So used to seeing comma delimited list questions. In that case they should be using a TVP instead with one row per search phrase.

Answer (score 4):

I would make a table-valued function, that splits string and creates table from it.
Code could look like this:

```
Create Function [dbo].[MyFunction]
(
    @List NVarChar(Max)
)
Returns @IDList TABLE 
(
    ID int 
)
With SchemaBinding
As
Begin
    Declare @myList NVarChar(Max);
    Declare @value NvarChar(Max);

    SET @myList = @List;

    While(Charindex(',', @myList) != 0)
    Begin
        SET @value = Substring(@myList , 1, Charindex(',', @myList) - 1);
        Insert Into @IDList (ID) Values (@value)
        SET @myList = Substring(@myList, Charindex(',', @myList) + 1, Len(@myList));
    End

    Insert Into @IDList (ID) Values (@myList)

    Return;
End
```

And then join tables.

Answer (score 3):

Does this help you? I wouldn't recommend doing this (for performance reasons) though..

```
 declare @keys varchar(max)
 set @keys = '1,200,123,44'

 select * from sometable where (',' + @keys + ',') like '%,' + sometable.key + ',%'
```

Comment: But keys are not number. That could be 'Gam,ra,Mo' and the data in table is Game, Raw and Movies.

Comment: @Kamlesh it will still work with "Gam,ra,Mo" - I just assumed numbers

Comment: Oh wait, you want "Gam,ra,Mo" to match "Game", "Raw", and "Movies"?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, then you might for example be searching the value `AA,BG,FR,DE` for a key like `BG` or `DE`. Assuming your list has not initial or trailing comma, then this ought to work in a `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE ',' + ListOfKeys + ',' LIKE '%,' + KeyToFind + ',%'
```

Comment: (copied text from OP's edit attempt) "Yes, you are right but I don't understand your point. Can you elaborate little bit more. Because I want to search the keys in table and the keys in string form"

Answer (score 0):

There are several other possible solutions. None of these are quick fixes and depending on your current design may take a lot of work, but the potential performance gains will justify doing the work.

If the data you are searching is stored in a comma delimited list, then the best possible solution is to fix your data model and store the data properely in a related table.

If your data is a long varchar max type field and you are searching for key terms within the document, then look at how to do Full text search. This will perform much better than any like statement.

Alternatively if you are storing large documents and you want to search them, consider using a document database instead of a relational database for this part of the project. They are better optimized for dealing with documents.